# jQuery hasData as a chain?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check if hasData exists in a chain?

E.g:

```
<div data-foo="yes">Foo</div>

$("div").hasData("foo").css("color","red");
```

Comment: `.hasClass` does not work like that.  It cannot be chained either.  It returns a boolean.

Comment: What do you expect `hasData` to return here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hasData = function (data) {
        if (this.data(data)) return this;
        else return null;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery method chaining still obeys the rules of JS. Since `hasData` returns a Boolean, and Booleans don't have jQuery methods, this doesn't work.

The easiest way to do this is to modify your selector so that the original collection is already filtered:

```
$("div[data-foo]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.filter` instead:

```
$("div").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("foo");
}).css("color","red");
```

Or even just an attribute selector:

```
$("div[data-foo]").css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/xrDf9/2/)

```
$("div[data-foo=yes]").css("color","red");
```